# Product listing - Product title is cutting - Advada theme, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have problem that i didn't find  how to solve it.
I am using Woocommerace (v3.3.3) in Advada template, in a category page I have all the products, its look with the source code that its do manipulation on Post product and rebuild it like a list with the product.
The problem is that the name of the product is getting cut and I want it to be fully length

This is how look 1 product in the list:

```html
<li class="post-12366 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-all product_cat-new product-grid-view instock sale shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
 <a href="url" class="product-images" aria-label="Enhancing Romantic Desire">

 <span class="onsale">Sale!</span>

<div class="featured-image">
  <img width="500" height="500" src="image">   <div class="cart-loading"><i class="fusion-icon-spinner"></i></div>
 </div>
</a>
<div class="br_alabel br_alabel_label br_alabel_type_text br_alabel_right" style="top:-10px;right:0px;"><span style="height: 50px;width: 50px;background-color:#245673;color:#ffffff;border-radius:50px;line-height:50px;">New!</span></div><div class="product-details">
 <div class="product-details-container">
<h3 class="product-title">
 <a href="https://url/product/enhancing-romantic-desire/">
  Enhancing Romantic Des </a>
</h3>
<div class="fusion-price-rating">

 <span class="price"><del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>150.00</span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>575.00</span></ins></span>
  </div>
  <div class="fusion-content-sep"></div>
 </div>
</div>

    <div class="product-buttons">
   <div class="product-buttons-container clearfix">
 <a href="/product-category/all/?add-to-cart=12366" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="12366" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add “Enhancing Romantic Desire” to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a><a href="url" class="show_details_button">
 Details</a>
 </div>
</div>
</li>
```

So under class product-title we can see the the title cut,
i tried to add function to change the name with :

```html
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','full_title',10);
```

but its only add before  the title and didn't replace it. i tried also to find which page is the source but didn't find it.

I think that there is function that cut the title length, i tried to find but no any result...

Any suggestion please?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You can register your own function here

```
function remove_avada_woocommerce_edits() {

    global $avada_woocommerce;
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', array( $avada_woocommerce, 'product_title' ), 10 );

}

add_action('init','remove_avada_woocommerce_edits');
```